# API in javascript is returning data, but is not being saved into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, wordpress, api

I am trying to fetch data from an API of WordPress.
Here is my code:

```
column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d,j) {
    var practiceArea = d.practice_area;
    var jsonPacticeArea = JSON.stringify(practiceArea);
    if (jsonPacticeArea !== undefined) {
        var res = $.map(jsonPacticeArea.split("|"), $.trim);
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
             var str = res[i];
             str = str.replace(/"/gi, '').trim();
             if (arrayPracticeArea.indexOf(str) === -1) {
                 arrayPracticeArea.push(str);
             }    
        }
    }
});
```

the "column" is the variable that is getting data through an API, and as far as I do console.log(column. data().unique().sort()), that's returning complete data as you can see in the screenshot [image] and I want to fetch data is marked in red rectangle and store those values in an array, but as soon as I try to add "each" function to fetch the data and store it in an array (in my case its arrayPracticeArea) its returning undefined values.

Can anyone please help me out? I am just not much experienced with Javascript API.

Here is my AJAX code:

```
var tableAttorney = $('#table_affliate_attorney').DataTable({
                    destroy: true,
                    searching: true,
                    bLengthChange: false,
                    scrollX: true,
                    scrollY: 440,
                    autoWidth: false,
                    "language": {
                        "emptyTable": "We are sorry but there are no Affiliate Attorneys within a 150 mile radius of your requested search"
                    },
                    ajax: {
                        type: 'get',
                        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false,
                        data: {
                            'action': 'get_attorney_ajax',
                            'center_lat': center_lat,
                            'center_long': center_long,
                            'state': state,
                            'city': city,
                            'zip': zip
                        }
                      
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {"data": "title"},
                        {"data": "city"},
                        {"data": "state"},
                        {"data": "zip"},
                        {"data": "distance"},
                        {
                            "data": "phone",
                            className: 'datatablePhone',
                            render: function (data) {
                                return '<a href="tel:' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "email",
                            className: 'px190EM',
                            render: function (data) {
                                return '<a href="mailto:' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            className: 'js-practice-area',
                            "data": "practice_area"
                        },
                        {
                            "targets": -1,
                            "data": 'email',
                            render: function (data) {
                                return "<a class='contact-lawyer' href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal' data-whatever='@mdo' data-email='"+data+"'>Contact</a>";
                            }
                        },
                        
                    ],
                    columnDefs: [
                        {"width": "150px", "targets": [0]},
                        {"width": "130px", "targets": [5]}
                    ],
```

So I am trying to fetch data from columns->data that has value practice_area

Comment: In what part of the code you've put `console.log` that shown in the screenshot?

Comment: vanowm I just did console.log before this whole function.

Comment: Ok, the screenshot shows that it's an array of 4 string items. But in your code you are trying get a `practice_area` property from an object.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just tried it now, but it's showing an error that the column is not iterable. I added that code inside the function which I have shown in the function.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `d` is what you are expecting with `console.log(d)`?

Comment: Yes, I just need practice_area that has value fetched from WordPress.

Comment: and the `d` contains....

Comment: Yes, I tried to console.log(d), it just outputs 655 undefined values. though the API is sending the data.

Comment: If you think you can help me, I can send the whole JS code so you can get a better idea about this whole stuff.

Comment: than start with the basics first. See what exactly `column` has, than `column.data()`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for getting interested in responding to me like that. Yes, of course, I tried the same way you said, firstly I tried to console.log(column.data()), then console.log(column.data().unique()) and the then console.log(column.data().unique().sort()) these are all displaying the right data in the form of Array, everything that the API is returning. But it does not work as soon as each function is applied.

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what `each()` function does in this api, perhaps you should try a vanilla javascript

Comment: I have added the full JS code here https://jsfiddle.net/fareeboy/apor08jn/
If you have some time, can you take a look into it? Maybe you can an idea by seeing my whole code.
Thanks